# Find the next image in this abstract reasoning puzzle

Tags: pattern, geometry, lateral-thinking

[image]

I have been looking for patterns for a while now, but could not find one.

I found some rules:

> 1. The middle column always points the same direction.
> 2. The first two in the first row are always opposite.
> 3. The last two in the second column are always opposite.

Still, these rules are insufficient.

Attribution: [EPSO online test](https://europa.eu/epso/application/passport/index.cfm?action=int_test&intact=dsp_ar_tests)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> C

because

> following each of the 6 positions through in sequence, the directions of the arrows rotate by 90 degrees clockwise each time except when they point up or down, where they stay twice in a row.

More details:

> Top left arrow: R,D,D,L,U, **U**
> Top middle arrow: L,U,U,R,D, **D**
> Top right arrow: D,D,L,U,U, **R**
> Bottom left arrow: U,R,D,D,L, **U**
> Bottom middle arrow: L,U,U,R,D, **D**
> Bottom right arrow: R,D,D,L,U, **U**
> (directions in which each arrow points)

Comment: Wow! Loving that rule. thx

Comment: Damn typing on mobile. Ya beat me to it. :)

Comment: @Alconja FGitW ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the arrow in the same location, you'll notice that they always rotate clockwise. But whenever they hit either up or down, they stay that way for two steps. In other words, each arrow follows the pattern: *up, up, right, down, down, left, ...*.

From there the solution is pretty clearly option *C*.

Comment: Thx. This is a good answer too! rand was a bit earlier, so I already accepted that.

Answer (score 3):

For me the obvious answer is:

> In first and fourth pattern the arrows point in opposite directions.
>  Likewise in the second and fifth pattern. Therefore the sixth pattern
>  should be the opposite of the third pattern, so the answer is C.

Comment: I guess  that the interesting part is that you were able to figure out what would be the next one in the sequence even if you hadn't to choose between possibilities. **C** is indeed the correct answer, but the reasoning you give could be improved.

Comment: In my opinion this reasoning is sound. The pattern @rijnswind found is there and leads to the correct answer. It may or may not be the reasoning that the puzzle creator intended but it is valid nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is C

It looks like the pattern is (1-4) (2-5) (3-?)

Each arrow in the same position in 1 and 4 are pointing in the opposite direction, as is the arrows in 2 and 5. On that basis image number 6 would be the same as 3 with the arrows pointing in the opposite direction. The only image that does this is C.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is

> **C**

Because

> All the pointers are rotating clockwise pointing up and down twice and sideways once.